# Can't access public property?

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework

I have this code retrieved from `var_dump($cache)` where $cache is the variable holding the object: http://pastebin.com/9Ufpzbdn (Sorry, code is hard to format here but it's not that long).

How do I access property $_redis?

I tried `$cache->_redis` but it says it's undefined.

I just want to access it so I can use its `set` and `fetch` methods.

I have not touched any php for awhile now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try:

```
$redis = $cache->getBackend()->_redis;
```